# Have a command acting on the environment body

Tags: macros, environments

I need to turn this

```
\begin{FOO}
my little pony
\end{FOO}
```

into this

```
\bar{my little pony}
```

I have tried this:

```
\newenvironment{FOO}{\bar}{}
```

But this seems to only make `\bar` apply on the first character, like so:

```
\bar{m}y little pony
```

Comment: I think the title is misleading. You rather want to have a command acting on the environment body

Comment: Doesn't `\newenvironment{FOO}{\bar\bgroup}{\egroup}` work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Admittedly, the example with `\color`) could be achieved without this, but let us assume `\mycmd` is more complex for the real case and not a toy 'theory';-))

Collecting the environment body is easiest with `environ` package and its `\NewEnviron` command and `\BODY`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{%
  \color{blue}#1%
}

\NewEnviron{FOO}{\mycmd{\BODY}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{FOO}
my little pony

\blindtext[2]
\end{FOO}

\end{document}
```

More complex examples might have to use a `\expandafter` before `\BODY`.

[image]

Comment: Please note that there might be cases where an `\expandafter` for the `\BODY` is necessary before the command `\mycmd` comes into action

Comment: `Collecting the environment body is easiest with environ`

How do you go about it in normal environments? (I can ask a new question if necessary)